How to improve gain for CC-CE-CC amplifier
I'm trying to design my first amplifier; my configuration is CC-CE-CC. My Vcc is 10V and Ic for 3 transistors are 0.5mA.
When i designed this, i wanted the overall gain to be 50 times, ( and around 90% of that (~45) when load is plugged in), with >20k input resistance, Vout p-p > 8V (without load) and >4V (with load)

The first stage: CC amplifier configuration, it is meant to increase the input resistance above 20k ohms

The second stage: CE amplifier configuration, it is meant to amplify the input signal 50 times (Av no load = 50)

The third stage: CC configuration, it is meant to stabilize the load 1K for the voltage gain not to drop further than 90% of no load voltage gain (~45)


Here is my design:

Problem:

When i tried to connect the oscilloscope to the CC-CE (1st and 2nd stage) the gain was approximately what i wanted ( Av ~50 as 80mV to 4V). However, i got a little bit of clipping at the bottom of the waveform.



I connected the third stage CC to the rest of the circuit (1st-2nd and 3rd stage together), my overall gain dropped to approximately 37.5. (My hypothesis is the gain of the third stage CC messed up my overall gain)



I connected the load rL = 1k to the rest of the circuit. the Av with load is lower than 90% of the Av without load and its also got clipping at the bottom of the waveform.


Questions:

What did i do wrong in choosing the resistors for CE amplifier? what resistor vlaues should i choose to get rid of the clipping and improve the gain?
What wrong in my third stage CC value? why did my Av dropped like that? I also wanted to get rid of the clipping too.
What should i be beware of when i design a multistage amplifier?

This is the first time I designed an amplifier.
I used multism to design my circuit.

Mark up onto your schematic all the DC voltages at each node (from your sim).

When designing discrete transistor amplifiers, it is helpful if the oscilloscope is set to DC coupling so you can see where the DC bias are.
The gain of the middle stage needs to take in to consideration all the impedances connected to the collector. This includes, at a first approximation, R4, R11, & R12. This parallel combination gives a collector impedance of 6.87k.
The internal emitter resistance, \$r'_e\$ needs to take in to consideration.
\$r'_e = V_T / I_E \approx 25mV/I_E\$.
At a first approximation, the gain of the second stage is about \$ 6870/(180+39) = 31.3\$.
As for clipping at the output of the third stage when a 1k load is connected, the emitter current needs to be increased. Setting R13 to a lower value will increase the current.

Thank you for your answer. May I ask wher did u get the number 180 and 39?

@jajalapeno R9 = 180 ohms. $r'_e \approx 39 $ ohms. Gain of a common emitter amplifier, as a first approximation, is $R_c / (r'_e + R_e)$.

The output impedance of stage 2 (Q1) is \$R_{OUT2}=R_4=9.1k\Omega\$, but it is being loaded by the potential divider of the following stage, whose input impedance is:
$$ R_{IN3} = R_{11} \parallel R_{12} = 28k\Omega $$
This forms a potential divider consisting of \$R_{OUT2}\$ and \$R_{IN3}\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This attenuates by a factor \$A_3=\frac{28k}{9.1k+28k}=0.75\$. Therefore the combined gain of the second and third stages is:
$$ A_2A_3 \approx 50 \times 0.75 \approx 37 $$
The quiescent potential at Q1's emitter is about +1.2V, and the collector can never fall below that. Consequently collector potential can only swing between +1.3V and +10V. You should aim to place quiescent collector potential in the middle of that range:
$$ V_{C(DC)} = \frac{1.3V + 10V}{2} = 5.7V $$
As it stands, I estimate it's closer to 4.5V in your circuit, meaning that clipping will much occur earlier on down-swings than up-swings. To achieve this quiescent collector potential, DC collector current will need to be reduced to 470μA or so, which can be achieved by increasing R3 to 2.5kΩ.
Since the output of stage 2 (Q1) is already biased near the supply mid-point, the emitter-follower of Q3 doesn't require any additional biasing, and you can directly couple those stages, eliminating the load caused by R11 and R12:

simulate this circuit

Several things:

You have three stages, but only one has gain.

You're trying to design it to get a particular amount of gain.

It's likely that the gain drop you see when adding the third stage is
from it loading the second stage.


What you might consider is making the first two stages CE for gain and the last CC for low output impedance. Design for considerably more gain than you need, then use negative feedback to bring it down to what you want. This has the added advantage of lowering distortion.
At 220 \$\mu\$F your coupling capacitors are probably much larger than you need (I've got a similar design that uses a 4.7 \$\mu\$F on the input), and you might also consider direct coupling the stages, it makes the biasing a bit trickier but it eliminates the interstage capacitors.
